# BST search problen

Tags: oop, binary-search-tree

I've implemented a BST that contains in it's n nodes an object of type Point (x,y), the order in the tree is according to the X's values.

I need to implement a function that getting as input the range of X's (x left, x right)
and the output is
**(EDIT)**:the sum of Y's coordinates in range(included).

it's not that hard doing it by "walking" throught all the nodes, the problem is the I asKed to do it in O(logn) comlexity.

I thought about intializing fields of ranges and sum of Y's, but somehow it doesn't work out with the insertion and deletion functions.
any ideas?

Comment: I'm pretty sure they meant `O(log n + |right-left|)`, which is still `O(log n)` but with more variables.

Comment: Alternatively, you can accumulate the sum over all points and cache it in every node, so that you quickly find the sum of the range by only looking at its edges.

Answer (score 0):

Finding each end of the range is `O(log n)` complexity. There is no need to look at all nodes in the tree.

If you are required to sum the numbers of a range, then taking the high boundary minus the low boundary (assuming a consecutive,  linear range), is a constant time operation.